# Python virtual environment make available to all projects

Tags: python, pycharm

Does this setting mean I can have multiple projects that use the same virtual environment? I created a new environment with the option checked, but it still shows "no interpreter" when I try to make a new project.
[image: No existing interpreter]

Comment: Please rewrite your explanation. Add some outputs, if possible.

Comment: "this setting" – which one?

Comment: I made a new virtual environment with the "Make available to all projects" option checked, but when creating a new project I can't find the environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on file then click on new project then click on the ... Button in existing interpreter then chose system interpreter and mark available to all projects[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new project, you can select the existing interpreter to use existing environments.

[image]

Comment: It shows that I don't have any existing interpreters even after I created a virtual environment already

Comment: @hugo have you check marked the box saying existing interpreter

Comment: @Rice I added a screenshot just now, it shows "no interpreter" but I just created another project with a new environment

Comment: @Rice sorry I meant that the new project doesn't show any available interpreters, despite creating an environment that is available to all projects

Comment: Hey do you have python installed in your comp or laptop

Comment: Yes, I can run code but I don't want to make a separate environment for each project